# xgboost.plot_tree: binary feature interpretation

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I've built an XGBoost model and seek to examine the individual estimators. For reference, this was a binary classification task with discrete and continuous input features. The input feature matrix is a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`.

When I went to examine an individual estimator, however, I found difficulty interpreting the binary input features, such as `f60150` below. The real-valued `f60150` in the bottommost chart is easy to interpret - its criterion is in the expected range of that feature. However, the comparisons being made for the binary features, `<X> < -9.53674e-07` doesn't make sense. Each of these features are either 1 or 0. `-9.53674e-07` is a very small negative number, and I imagine this is just some floating-point idiosyncrasy within XGBoost or its underpinning plotting libraries, but it doesn't make sense to use that comparison when the feature is always positive. Can someone help me understand which direction (i.e. `yes, missing` vs. `no` corresponds to which true/false side of these binary feature nodes?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from xgboost import plot_tree, XGBClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def booleanize_csr_matrix(mat):
    ''' Convert sparse matrix with positive integer elements to 1s '''
    nnz_inds = mat.nonzero()
    keep = np.where(mat.data > 0)[0]
    n_keep = len(keep)
    result = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(
        (np.ones(n_keep), (nnz_inds[0][keep], nnz_inds[1][keep])),
        shape=mat.shape
    )
    return result

### Setup dataset
res = fetch_20newsgroups()

text = res.data
outcome = res.target

### Use default params from CountVectorizer to create initial count matrix
vec = CountVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(text)

# Whether to "booleanize" the input matrix
booleanize = True

# Whether to, after "booleanizing", convert the data type to match what's returned by `vec.fit_transform(text)`
to_int = True

if booleanize and to_int:
    X = booleanize_csr_matrix(X)
    X = X.astype(np.int64)

# Make it a binary classification problem
y = np.where(outcome == 1, 1, 0)

# Random state ensures we will be able to compare trees and their features consistently
model = XGBClassifier(random_state=100)
model.fit(X, y)

plot_tree(model, rankdir='LR'); plt.show()
```

Running the above with `booleanize` and `to_int` set to `True` yields the following chart:

[image]

Running the above with `booleanize` and `to_int` set to `False` yields the following chart:

[image]

Heck, even if I do a really simple example, I get the "right" results, regardless of whether `X` or `y` are integer or floating types.

```
X = np.matrix(
    [
        [1,0],
        [1,0],
        [0,1],
        [0,1],
        [1,1],
        [1,0],
        [0,0],
        [0,0],
        [1,1],
        [0,1]
    ]
)

y = np.array([1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1])

model = XGBClassifier(random_state=100)
model.fit(X, y)

plot_tree(model, rankdir='LR'); plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You sure have not applied any *preprocessing*, which may render binary features `f264` and `f3282` taking negative values?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I just reloaded the matrix and ran `X[X < 0]` and `(X < 0).sum()`... Got zero for both

Comment: I think previously xgboost wasn't really good with categorical variables. This was one of the reasons for introduction of https://catboost.ai/en/docs/. The 1.5 version of xgboost introduced an experimental support for categorical variables. https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html. Although as of today it still seems experimental. I don't think this comment will help you given more than 4 years since posting, but I hope this helps someone with similar problem

Answer (score -1):

The comparison values you see in the XGBoost tree visualization are typically used to split the data into two branches in decision trees. In the case of binary features, like the ones created by your `booleanize_csr_matrix` function, the comparisons are indeed used to determine which branch (True or False) a sample should follow.

In the context of your XGBoost binary classification model:

- If a binary feature, like `f60150`, has a comparison such as `<X> < -9.53674e-07`, this means that the tree is splitting samples based on whether the value of feature `f60150` is less than `-9.53674e-07`.
- If the feature is always positive (i.e., 1 or 0), the comparisons should still be interpreted the same way. The comparison `<X> < -9.53674e-07` is essentially equivalent to "Is `f60150` equal to 0 or 1?"

XGBoost may represent binary features in a way that uses floating-point numbers for splitting, but the comparison still serves the purpose of separating samples into different branches based on the feature's value. In practice, this small negative number is used as a threshold for splitting, but it doesn't affect the interpretation of the binary feature.

So, in the case of binary features, the comparison values are used to determine whether the feature is 0 or 1, and this is how the tree makes decisions during classification. For binary features, these comparisons are typically straightforward and are used to separate samples into two groups: one where the feature is 0 and the other where the feature is 1.